# Cannot compile and run Android Market API

Tags: java

I am sorry for the very basic question but I feel truly lost here. What I am trying to do is to compile and run this code:

```
package com.gc.android.market.api;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.InputStream;

import com.gc.android.market.api.MarketSession;

import com.gc.android.market.api.MarketSession.Callback;
import com.gc.android.market.api.model.Market.AppType;
import com.gc.android.market.api.model.Market.AppsRequest;
import com.gc.android.market.api.model.Market.AppsRequest.OrderType;
import com.gc.android.market.api.model.Market.AppsRequest.ViewType;
import com.gc.android.market.api.model.Market.AppsResponse;
import com.gc.android.market.api.model.Market.CommentsRequest;
import com.gc.android.market.api.model.Market.GetAssetResponse.InstallAsset;
import com.gc.android.market.api.model.Market.GetImageRequest;
import com.gc.android.market.api.model.Market.GetImageResponse;
import com.gc.android.market.api.model.Market.ResponseContext;
import com.gc.android.market.api.model.Market.GetImageRequest.AppImageUsage;

public class Fetcher
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MarketSession session = new MarketSession(true);
        System.out.println("Login:");
    }
}
```

I am following the instructions from here: https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/wiki/HowDownloadApps

The import and package lines I got from here: https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/source/browse/trunk/AndroidMarketApi/src/com/gc/android/market/api/Main.java

I am doing this on OS X. In my current directory I have three files:

- Fetcher.java (the code above)
- AndroidMarketApi.jar
- protobuf-java-2.2.0.jar

I compile using this command:

```
$ javac -classpath ".:/Users/ephracis/fetcher/*" Fetcher.java
```

I then try to run:

```
$ java Fetcher
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Fetcher (wrong name: com/gc/android/market/api/Fetcher)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
$ java com.gc.android.market.api.Fetcher
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gc/android/market/api/Fetcher
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gc.android.market.api.Fetcher
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I've also tried to add the classpath to the java command but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: And what happens? Does your computer explode, or is it something more mundane?

Comment: The error is included in my question.

Answer (score 0):

To execute you need the fully qualified class name (package + class name). Try:

```
java -classpath ".:/Users/ephracis/fetcher/*" com.gc.android.market.api.Fetcher
```

Also, you still need to include the appropriate classes/jars on the classpath.

Comment: I have tried both class name and package + class name, with and without the classpath flag. I included both tries (without classpath flag) in my question. Adding the classpath flag doesn't change the error I get.